# Call an arbitrary JSON-RPC method with web3

Tags: web3js, testrpc

I want to use web3 to call `evm_snapshot` (only available on testrpc). This is not in web3's list of methods, but I don't want to have to make an actual http call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to `sendAsync,` you can extend web3 like so:

```
    web3._extend({
        property: 'evm',
        methods: [new web3._extend.Method({
            name: 'snapshot',
            call: 'evm_snapshot',
            params: 0,
            outputFormatter: toIntVal
        })]
    });

    web3._extend({
        property: 'evm',
        methods: [new web3._extend.Method({
            name: 'revert',
            call: 'evm_revert',
            params: 1,
            inputFormatter: [toIntVal]
        })]
    });
```

That way you can use the command just like any other method, so it's far more readable.

Also, if you don't want to deal with implementing these methods yourself, you can use my [extended web3](https://github.com/tjade273/web3_extended/)

Comment: Are these documented anywhere?

Comment: For web3 >1.0.0 https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html#extend. I don't know if there's docs for web3 <1.0.0, which is what this answer is based on

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Yeah I couldn't find it in 0.20.x. Also can't find sendAsync docs.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like I can use `web3.currentProvider.sendAsync()`.

```
web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
  method: "eth_getBalance",
  params: ['0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1', 'latest'],
  jsonrpc: "2.0",
  id: new Date().getTime()
} function (error, result) {...})
```

Comment: +1 for dynamic id generation for avoiding collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Improving a bit Jehan's answer:

```
  window.ethereum.sendAsync({
  method: "eth_getBalance",
  params: ['0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1', 'latest'],
  jsonrpc: "2.0",
  id: new Date().getTime()
} , function (error, result){
           console.log(result);
       });
```