# Calling debug_traceTransaction from web3 API

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I want to use debug.traceTransaction to get internal transactions from NodeJS using web3 API.
I'm using web3 0.17 beta and I don't see any debug_traceTransaction on the code. Am I missing something or I have to call directly to the RPC?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As documented in [`debug.traceTransaction(...)`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#debug_tracetransaction), you can only access this API call using the `geth` JavaScript console or the JSON-RPC API. There is no web3 API that I know of. There are some unofficial extension web3 APIs, but I don't know if `debug.traceTransaction` is supported by these. Looks like you have to use JSON-RPC to access this data.

### `geth` JavaScript API

Start `geth` with the appropriate parameters to enable RPC and the `debug` module:

```
geth --cache=1024 --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,debug" console
```

We can trace the transaction [0x3684f071b34da1116282ee88a106a8f2a266d273ef7d8964957f65128fb58d77](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3684f071b34da1116282ee88a106a8f2a266d273ef7d8964957f65128fb58d77) in the `geth` console:

```
> debug.traceTransaction("0x3684f071b34da1116282ee88a106a8f2a266d273ef7d8964957f65128fb58d77")
{
  gas: 45480,
  returnValue: "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
  structLogs: [{
      depth: 1,
      error: "",
      gas: 76741,
      gasCost: 3,
      memory: null,
      op: "PUSH1",
      pc: 0,
      stack: [],
      storage: {}
    ...
```

### JSON-RPC API

And here is an example trace using the JSON-RPC API:

```
curl localhost:8545 -X POST --header 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"debug_traceTransaction", "params":["0x3684f071b34da1116282ee88a106a8f2a266d273ef7d8964957f65128fb58d77", {}], "id":1}'
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"gas":45480,"returnValue":"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001","structLogs":[{"pc":0,"op":"PUSH1","gas":76741,"gasCost":3,"depth":1,"error":"","stack":[],"memory":null,"storage":{}} ...
```

See also:

- [Call an arbitrary JSON-RPC method with web3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3885/call-an-arbitrary-json-rpc-method-with-web3)
- [How can I make new account by JSON-RPC?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/how-can-i-make-new-account-by-json-rpc)

---

### Update Dec 19 2016 Responding To `@Avatar`'s Comment Below

(Including the comment below `@Pablo Yabo`'s answer)

If I start `geth` using the following command line:

```
Iota:~ user$ geth --rpc console
```

And I try to execute the following `curl` command:

```
Iota:~ user$ curl localhost:8545 -X POST --header 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"debug_traceTransaction", "params":["0x3684f071b34da1116282ee88a106a8f2a266d273ef7d8964957f65128fb58d77", {}], "id":1}'
```

I get the following result:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"The method debug_traceTransaction does not exist/is not available"}}
```

If instead I start `geth` with the following command:

```
Iota:~ user$  geth --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,debug" console
```

And I run the same `curl` command, I get the transaction trace as shown below:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"gas":45480,"returnValue":"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001","structLogs":[{"pc":0,"op":"PUSH1","gas":76741,"gasCost":3,"depth":1,"error":null,"stack":[],"memory":null,"storage":{}},{"pc":2,"op":"PUSH1","gas":76738,"gasCost":3,"depth":1,"error":null,"stack":["0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060"],"memory":null,"storage":{}},{ ...
```

Also note that you cannot get the `debug_traceTransaction` information from the section of the blockchain that you have `--fast` synced.

Comment: I get err == null but the result contains an error "Missing trie node fc764c15d494d80384b70d1eccf399af403eb7eb91f17da32bd1729d722374... (length: 82)". Does it mean that my blockchain is incomplete?

Comment: I confirm that was the case. After restarting the blockchain without any --fast modificator it works perfect.

Comment: Could we call  debug.traceTransaction(...) through nodejs? The answer below confused my mind, thanks.

Comment: `@Avatar`, see the update to my answer above.

Answer (score 8):

Just to ease things. In NodeJS:

```
var web3 = require('../tools/web3');
web3.web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
    method: "debug_traceTransaction",
    params: ['0x3fac854179691e377fc1aa180b71a4033b6bb3bde2a7ef00bc8e78f849ad356e', {}],
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: "2"
}, function (err, result) {
    ...
});
```

Works perfect! If your blockchain was downloaded with --fast you will have to download it again.

Comment: It gives the error as: "{ jsonrpc: '2.0',
  id: '2',
  error:
   { code: -32601,
     message: 'The method debug_traceTransaction does not exist/is not available' } }"

Comment: Your blockchain was downloaded with --fast so it doesn't contain debug information. You should download it again without --fast.

Comment: I did not use `--fast` to download the blockchain. @Pablo Yabo

Comment: It looks the debug information isn't there. Maybe it was downloaded by an old version which didn't get debug information. I suggest downloading it again. You can do it in a VM and you can test if it works as soon as it downloads the first block, you don't need to wait until finishes it.

Comment: i'm using infura instance and getting the same issue "The method debug_traceTransaction does not exist/is not available"