# How to use ethereumjs-vm to find the internal transactions for a transaction/block using infura.io

Tags: ethereumjs, ethereumjs-tx

I am using infura.io as my node and trying to get the internal transactions (i.e. transfers initiated by smart contract) for a specific transaction (or its parent block). I have two attempts (both erroring out). It feels like I am missing something basic here.

Some setup code:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const VM = require('ethereumjs-vm');
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
const blockFromRpc = require('ethereumjs-block/from-rpc');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/' + process.env.INFURA_API_KEY));

const vm = new VM();
```

When I try this:

```
web3.eth.getTransaction('0x6b871b7db60454cf97fe7b5d0bb1192f23984e35990dfeeb8df5b9295d0eaaf5')
    .then(tx => {
        web3.eth.getBlock(6189875)
            .then(block => {
                try {
                    vm.runTx({
                        tx: new Tx({
                            ...tx,
                            data: tx.input
                        }),
                        block: blockFromRpc(block)
                    }, function(err, results){
                        console.log('returned: ' + results.logs);
                    });
                }
                catch(e) {
                    const i = e;
                }
            });
    });
```

I get an error:

> The sender does not have enough ether to send this tx

and when I try this:

```
web3.eth.getBlock(6189875)
    .then(block => {
        try {
            vm.runBlock({
                block: blockFromRpc(block),
                //block
            }, function(err, results){
                console.log('returned: ' + results.logs);
            });
        }
        catch(e) {
            const i = e;
        }
    });
```

I get an error:

> base free exceeds gas limit

Whats going  on? I just want to replay the transaction or block so that I can see the internal transactions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know about Infura, but I have my solution to export all internal transactions from the blockchain. It exports everything into SQL DB. I have also got `approvals` and `transfers` in separate tables. Historic balances of the token accounts and other cool stuff. The code is in development right now , but If interested, leave your contract data and I will send it to you.

Comment: @Nulik I don't really want to maintain an ethereum node. Do you know of any solution where I can use a remote node?

Comment: then you need a node that supports transaction tracing, sort of like this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9434/calling-debug-tracetransaction-from-web3-api , also I suggest checking Parity, maybe they have got more advanced on this subject.

Comment: @Nulik I haven't been able to find one (infura doesn't as far as I know). Also, the issue is that I would probably be rate limited. On another note, I've seen `GetModifiedAccountsByNumber` floating around. Do you know of any way I could access that on a public node?

Comment: You need the functionality that appeared in geth 1.8 , `callTracer` https://blog.ethereum.org/2018/02/14/geth-1-8-iceberg%C2%B9/ , it will give you internal transaction in an easy JSON array . `GetModifiedAccountsByNumber` is also part of the `debug` module which requies to be enabled by node administrator

Comment: @Nulik Do you know of any publicly available nodes that have that functionality?

Comment: No I dont know. But there is a list of nodes at ethernodes.org , maybe you could make a script to scan them